# CSS: fit image inside div

Tags: css

I want to remove the white line below the following image:

[image]

My CSS:

```
#content {
  float: left;
  background:#FFF;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#container img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto
}
```

My html:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="container">
    <img src="img/lib.JPG" width="100%"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

***I tried so many tricks but non of them is working in all the browsers***

Comment: Please provide a working example of your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `width="100%"` is not valid in html5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img` is inline element so by default there is space for descenders on letters like g, j. So to fix that you can just add `vertical-align: top` on image.

[image]

```css
#content {
  float: left;
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#container img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much finally fixed it ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out. I have added display block and border 0 to the image tag.

```css
#content {
float: left;
background:#FFF;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#container {
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
#container img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
display:block;
border:0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div id="container">
<img src="img/lib.JPG" width="100%"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `vertical-align: middle` to the image will fix that gap below it. You may also set `vertical-align` to `bottom` if you need, it will work as well.

In the below demo snippet, I added one more property `object-fit` to the image, with it you may specify the acquisition nature of the box in the available space.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  float: left;
  background: #FFF;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="container">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/g/1200/800">
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it was helpful.